# How to get the sum of integers in multiple objects?

Tags: c#, object, integer

I have two objects they are: Student and Courses:

```
public Student(string StudentID, string Name, string Status, Enum StudentMajor, Dictionary<Courses, Grade[]> CompletedCourses)

public Courses(string courseName, string courseCode, string passingGrade, int numOfCredits, List<Courses> prerequisites)
```

Here's the objects I created in my Main class

```
//Courses
Courses ITEC_120 = new("Introduction to Computer Hardware", "ITEC 120", "C", 3, new List<Courses> {});
Courses ITEC_122 = new("Introduction to Operating Systems", "ITEC 122", "C", 3, new List<Courses> { ITEC_120 });

//Student
Student student1 = new("00069110", "Antony Dos Santos", "Full-time", Majors.Computer_Information_Systems, new Dictionary<Courses, Grade[]>()
{
 { ITEC_120, new[] { Grade.F, Grade.B, Grade.Not_Taken } },
 { ITEC_122, new[] { Grade.A, Grade.Not_Taken, Grade.Not_Taken } 
},
});
```

As you can see the courses have a variable called `credit` and each `Student` object has a dictionary that takes a `Course` and a `Grade`

So `student1` has two courses and each of the courses has 3 credits each. How would I iterate over the Dictionary to get the total of all the courses in `CoursesCompleted` in this case it should be 6.

Each object is added to a List

```
//List for Courses objects
List<Courses> CompulsoryCourses = new List<Courses>();
CompulsoryCourses.Add(ITEC_120);
CompulsoryCourses.Add(ITEC_122);//Adding the two courses to the List

List for Student objects
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
students.Add(student1);

foreach(var stu in students)
{
var GPA = 0.0;
var CourseCredits = 0;
Console.WriteLine("\nStudent Information");
foreach (KeyValuePair<Courses, Grade[]> item in stu.CompletedCourses)
{
    var TotalCredits = CourseCredits+item.Key.numOfCredits;
    Console.WriteLine("\nName: " + item.Key.courseName + ", Credits: " + item.Key.numOfCredits);
    GPA = stu.calGPA(CourseCredits);
    Console.WriteLine("Total Credits: "+TotalCredits);
}
Console.WriteLine(stu.Name+ ": GPA = " + GPA);

}
```

In the foreach loop above I'm looping through the students List, and then I use another foreach loop to iterate the Dictionary to get the `Key` which in this case is `numOfCredits` like: `item.Key.numOfCredits`, and add them to each other.

Currently it's only adding the `numOfCredits` to itself and not to the other course in the dictionary.

Comment: Well, do you know how to _access_ some property/field in some object?

Comment: `TotalPrice_of_both_cars = car1.Price + car2.Price`

Comment: @EricJ. I want it to be dynamic, I think your solution will not be correct if another object was added.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace do you mean by using the dot operator?

Comment: Neither is a list of variables dynamic: you can't just create a new variable in your program at runtime, so first you need a dynamic construct before you can talk about dynamic summing.

Comment: Your question suffers from multiple personality disorder. Honestly, it's a mess. It begins with Cars and asking how to add prices, then suddenly it talks about students, courses, grades, stuff that's entirely unrelated to and different from the first third of the question.

Comment: There is some heavy editing here. The question is about students and grades, and the answers are about cars and prices.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou yes there is I removed the original question because someone said that it made the question messy, which it did. I may delete it.

Comment: Each `Course` should have one `Grade` for each student. So the structure `Dictionary<Courses, Grade[]> CompletedCourses` seems like a design problem.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou no, in theory a Student can do the course a maximum of 3 times, so if they got an F the first time, that will be the value of the 0 index of the Grade[] array, if they got an F the second time that will be the 1 index of and array and if they get an A on the third try, then A would be the grade that the student received in that course.

Comment: @NewDev so a dictionary isn't a good design, A dictionary is a 1:1 table. One value for each key.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou well it was recommend by a stack user, what do you suggest is the appropriate collection?

Comment: @NewDev - isn't only _one_ of the three grades important as far as GPA goes? Or is there some kind of averaging going on also?

Comment: @Yes only one of the three, and yes to calculate the GPA I'll need the total of all completed courses credits in the dictionary. The total credits is not all I need to calculate the GPA but it's a step that is needed to move on.

Comment: " the total of all completed courses credits" - this includes the credits of classes with failing grade (`Grade < PassingGrade`) that is are repeated? So for a 3 credit class first with a fail `F=0.0`, and then with a pass `C=2.0` grade the contribution is going to be `(..+3*0.0 + 3*2.0 + ..)/(.. 3  + 3 ..)` ? This means that there is indeed averaging going on and so failing courses need to be accounted for appropriately.   It would be nice if all those details were explained in the posting.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I got it to work. I changed the dictionary from `<Courses, Grade[]> to <Courses, int[]` so I used floating point values instead of Enum values. And for me to get the total of all the credits in the course I had to use the addition assignment operator `(+=)`  `var credits = 0.0; credits += item.Key.numOfCredits;`.

Comment: @NewDev - I just posted a solution that meets your requirements, for your reference. Indeed you need a way to translate `enum Grades` into grade values (especially if you want to implement `B+` type of grades) and all I am doing is a simple conversion `(int)grade` but I also made sure that `F=0`, `D=1`, `C=2`, `B=3` and `A=4`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) for something like this. If you have a list of cars and want to sum just the price you can do this:

```
var cars = new List<Car>
{
    new Car{ BrandName = "Lamborghini", Model = "Huracan", Price = 300000M },
    new Car{ BrandName = "Porsche", Model = "Gt3rs", Price = 200000M },
    new Car{ BrandName = "Vauxhall", Model = "Corsa", Price = 20000M }
};

var totalPrice = cars.Sum(car => car.Price);

Console.WriteLine($"Total Price: {totalPrice}");
```

Where 'Car' looks like this:

```
public class Car
{
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking for. But adding the sum of the cars "prices" i assume.

You could create a list, where all cars are added, along with all new cars.
Then what you could do it creating a for loop, thats the lengt of that spesific list. And through that loop add all values. Would look something like this:

Class creation

```
    class Car
    {
        public string name;
        public int price;

        public Car(string name, int price)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }
    }
```

Then for creating the list, and adding some cars.

```
            Car car1 = new Car("blue-car", 15);
            Car car2 = new Car("red-car", 15);


            List<Car> cars = new List<Car>() { car1, car2 };
```

And then finnaly we count the sum up.

```
            int totalprice = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < cars.Count; i++)
            {
                totalprice = totalprice + cars[i].price;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Output

If have only `Student` and `Course` classes (for simplification) and want this

```text
Name: Andy
Credits: 4
GPA: 2.25
    Course    Credits  Grade P/F
    ITEC 100  1        C     Fail
    ITEC 100  1        B     Pass
    ITEC 122  3        C     Pass

Name: Jill
Credits: 4
GPA: 3.75
    Course    Credits  Grade P/F
    ITEC 100  1        B     Pass
    ITEC 120  3        A     Pass

Name: Peter
Credits: 4
GPA: 2.5
    Course    Credits  Grade P/F
    ITEC 100  1        A     Pass
    ITEC 122  3        C     Pass

Name: Rosy
Credits: 4
GPA: 2.25
    Course    Credits  Grade P/F
    ITEC 100  1        B     Pass
    ITEC 122  3        F     Fail
    ITEC 122  3        D     Fail
    ITEC 122  3        C     Pass
```

but with the additional logic of tracking passing and/or falling classes, and restrictions on re-enrolling into classes etc, then look at the example below:

#### Program

The test program below defines 3 classes and 5 students. Then enrolls students to classes and assigns grades. Finally it loops through each student and each class the student has taken to enumerate their grades, and also calculate GPA

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var courses = new List<Course>
        {
            new Course("ITEC 100", "Introduction to Project Managment", 1, Grade.B),
            new Course("ITEC 122", "Introduction to Operating Systems", 3, Grade.C),
            new Course("ITEC 120", "Introduction to Computer Hardware", 3, Grade.D),
        };

        var students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student("Andy"),
            new Student("Jill"),
            new Student("Peter"),
            new Student("Rosy"),
        };

        students[0].EnrolledInClass(courses[0], Grade.C);   // fail
        students[0].EnrolledInClass(courses[0], Grade.B);   // pass
        students[0].EnrolledInClass(courses[1], Grade.C);   // pass

        students[1].EnrolledInClass(courses[0], Grade.B);   
        students[1].EnrolledInClass(courses[2], Grade.A);

        students[2].EnrolledInClass(courses[0], Grade.A);   
        students[2].EnrolledInClass(courses[1], Grade.C);

        students[3].EnrolledInClass(courses[0], Grade.B);   
        students[3].EnrolledInClass(courses[1], Grade.F);   // fail
        students[3].EnrolledInClass(courses[1], Grade.D);   // fail
        students[3].EnrolledInClass(courses[1], Grade.C);   // fail


        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {student.Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Credits: {student.TotalCredits}");
            Console.WriteLine($"GPA: {student.GPA}");
            Console.WriteLine($"    {"Course", -9} {"Credits",-8} {"Grade",-5} {"P/F",-5}");
            foreach ((Course course, Grade grade) in student.Courses)
            {
                string pass = course.IsPassing(grade) ? "Pass" : "Fail";
                Console.WriteLine($"    {course.Code, -9} {course.Credits,-8} {grade,-5} {pass,-5}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

}
```

#### Logic

Most of the logic is in the `Courses` class where a particular grade is checked to see if it passes, it calculates the rewarded credit hours and the awarded credit-grades.

The data is stored in a private `List<(Course,Grade)>` per student, and methods exist to check if you *can* enroll and to enroll students as well as calculate credit hours and GPA.

```
public enum Grade
{
    F = 0,
    D,
    C,
    B,
    A,
}

public class Student
{
    private readonly List<(Course course, Grade grade)> _courses;

    public Student(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        _courses = new List<(Course, Grade)>();
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public IReadOnlyList<(Course course, Grade grade)> Courses => _courses;

    public int FirstIndexOf(Course course) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Courses.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = Courses[i];
            if (item.course == course)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public int LastIndexOf(Course course) 
    {
        for (int i = Courses.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var item = Courses[i];
            if (item.course == course)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public bool HasTakenCourse(Course course)
    {
        return FirstIndexOf(course) >= 0;
    }
    public bool HasPassedCourse(Course course)
    {
        int index = LastIndexOf(course);
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            var item = Courses[index];
            return course.IsPassing(item.grade);
        }
        return false;
    }
    public bool CanEnrollInCourse(Course course)
    {
        int takenCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Courses.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = Courses[i];
            if (item.course == course)
            {                    
                if (course.IsPassing(item.grade))
                {
                    // Cannot enroll twice in same class with passing grade
                    return false;
                }
                takenCount++;
                if (takenCount > 3)
                {
                    // Cannot enroll in class > 3 times
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool EnrolledInClass(Course course, Grade grade)
    {
        if (CanEnrollInCourse(course))
        {
            _courses.Add((course, grade));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }        

    public int TotalCredits
    {
        get
        {
            return Courses.Sum((item) => item.course.GetCredits(item.grade));
        }
    }

    public float GPA
    {
        get
        {
            float creditGrades = Courses.Sum((item) => item.course.GetCreditGrade(item.grade));
            return creditGrades / TotalCredits;
        }
    }
}

public class Course
{
    public Course(string code, string description, int credits, Grade passingGrade = Grade.D)
    {
        Code = code;
        Description = description;
        Credits = credits;
        PassingGrade = passingGrade;
    }
    public string Code { get; }
    public string Description { get; }
    public int Credits { get; }
    public Grade PassingGrade { get; }
    public bool IsPassing(Grade grade) => grade >= PassingGrade;            // check if grade is passing
    public int GetCredits(Grade grade) => IsPassing(grade) ? Credits : 0;   // only credit passing grades
    public float GetCreditGrade(Grade grade) => GetCredits(grade) * (int)grade; // combine credit hours with grades, or zero for fail
}
```